# Karma Invalid config file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

In order to make karma config file easier to configure path, I am using variable to store certain part of the path.

```
var publicfolder = "public"
var mypath = "packages/vendor/package/";

files: [
  publicfolder+'/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  publicfolder+'/assets/libs/angular/angular.js',
  publicfolder+'/assets/libs/**/*.js',
  publicfolder+'/app/**/*.js',
  mypath +'/public/app/**/*.test.js',
  mypath +'/public/app/**/*.html'
],

preprocessors: {
    mypath +'/public/app/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
},
```

However, when I run the test, it come into the error saying

```
E:\www\project\karma.conf.js:83
    mypath +'/public/app/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
           ^
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

My question is WHY? Why I can't put variable there? Why is that it is fine to put it in the `files` array but not in the `preprocessors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preprocessors` is an object and you can't put expressions in an object key using [initializer notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers). You can use expressions if you are setting the key using [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

So in this case you could do something like this:

```
var mypath = "packages/vendor/package/";
var preprocessors = {};
preprocessors[mypath +'/public/app/**/*.html'] = ['ng-html2js'];
```

It's fine to use expressions in the `files` array because there you are just creating regular strings, not object keys.